# C# Can I display an Attribute of an Object in a Dictionary as ListControl.DisplayMember?

Tags: c#, dictionary, listcontrol

The aim is to see the list as a list of 'name's.

Here's the dictionary:

```
class Scripts
    {
        public Dictionary<int, Script> scripts = new Dictionary<int, Script>();
        ...
    }
```

Here's the attribute 'name' I'm after:

```
class Script
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        ...
    }
```

And here's the problem:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    Scripts allScripts;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        allScripts = new Scripts();
        setupDataSources();
    }

    private void setupDataSources()
    {
        BindingSource ketchup = new BindingSource(allScripts.scripts, null);
        //THIS LINE:
        listBoxScripts.DisplayMember = allScripts.scripts["Key"].name.ToString();
        listBoxScripts.ValueMember = "Key";
        listBoxScripts.DataSource = ketchup;
    }
    ...
}
```

I just can't think how to make that line work! Your advice is much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can binding to `Value` and override `ToString` method in `Script` class.

```
private void setupDataSources()
{            
    BindingSource ketchup = new BindingSource(allScripts.scripts, null);
    listBoxScripts.DisplayMember = "Value";
    listBoxScripts.ValueMember = "Key";
    listBoxScripts.DataSource = ketchup;            
}
```

Script class:

```
class Script
{
    public string name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the actual **value** of 'name' as the DisplayMember, so unless you randomly get a value in 'name' set to the same text as a property then you'll never get it displayed.

You'd be better off just doing:

```
listBoxScripts.DisplayMember = "name";
```

Surely?

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the dictionary element as a Script object

```
listBoxScripts.DisplayMember = ((Script)allScripts.scripts["Key"]).name.ToString();
```